# Why doesn't it work when I hover on the image?

Tags: css

I'm sure this is incredibly stupid once I get a hint, but I can't see why the hover doesn't work. I added the jQuery just to check whether or not it works with a click.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".figure", function() {
  $(".popover").css("opacity", "1");
})
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.popover {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 200px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.figure:hover .popover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='figure'>
    <img src='https://placehold.it/100' />
  </div>
  <div class='popover'>
    <p>
      Bla bla
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: .figure:hover + .popover {opacity : 1} try this code .   .figure and .popover are siblings , so you need to use sibling selector to get the work done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your `.popover` div is not a  child of `.figure` div.

Used `+` selector for this

```js
$(document).on("click", ".figure", function() {
  $(".popover").css("opacity", "1");
})
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.popover {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 200px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.figure:hover + .popover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='figure'>
    <img src='https://placehold.it/100' />
  </div>
  <div class='popover'>
    <p>
      Bla bla
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Right, in fact using `.container:hover .popover {}` it works

Answer (score 0):

**Change :**

```
.figure:hover .popover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**To :**

```
.figure:hover + .popover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing classes into id´s and than make hover.

**[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/md86t8dx/)**

```
#figure:hover + #popover {
   opacity:1;
}
```